# Baseline change in RF amplifier after peak

Tags: amplifier, rf, oscillation

I have made an RF amplifier based on the [MiniCircuits PSA4-5043+](https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=PSA4-5043%2B). The circuit is very similar to the one in [the evaluation board by MiniCircuits](https://www.minicircuits.com/pcb/WTB-653+_P02.pdf). The layout was changed a bit but not much, and I am using [the suggested bias T](https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=TCBT-14%2B). The main difference I would say is that in the input I don't have an RF line but rather a radiation detector installed very close to the amplifier, less than 1 cm away, like this:

[image]

which produces fast signals pulses. These radiation detectors I know very well because I have used a lot with a different amplifier.

Now, when I look at the signals in the output with the scope I get this:

[image]

The peak looks good, but there is this change in the baseline that I have indicated in red. Zooming out it looks like this:

[image]

i.e. a damped low frequency oscillation.The signals are all with different amplitude because of the different energies deposited by the particles in the sensor, but over time it ends up looking like this:

[image]

**What could be the reason for this?**

I am trying to simulate this behavior but I don't think it can be replicated with a linear circuit like this

[image]

because the kink in the signal at ~4 ns (see oscilloscope) looks non linear.

Comment: Where's your 50 ohm output load resistor? This will be a significant issue to signal shape and quite possibly the wavy line that follows.

Comment: It is the oscilloscope.

Comment: Is that a large-area diode? How much capacitance at zero  DC bias?

Comment: Yes, it is a large area diode. The capacitance varies from device to device, at 0 V it should be around 300 pF and at working voltage around 3 pF roughly.

Comment: *"It is the oscilloscope"*...So that trailing-edge transient disappears when you **DC-couple** perhaps? I'd think the 'scope input RC time constant would be far longer. I was thinking it might have something to do with the diode capacitance, C3 and amplifier input impedance.

Comment: Nono, the oscilloscope is the 50 Ω load to the circuit. I guess the low frequency thing also has to do with some RC in the circuit, but it looks like a non linear behavior, it is not the typical undershoot but rather a change in the baseline.

Comment: NB: I don't think that minicircuits are for "transient" inputs. You should "model" your detector. 10nH wiring should be "enough" for this behavior.

Comment: @Antonio51 I added the inductor in the input and it produces an oscillation but different in nature. I suspect that the amplifier is working fine, all parameters are fine, and the low frequency is something else (e.g. the ground shifting due to the power consumption of the amp and slowly coming back to normal or something like this). It looks like 2 different effects superimposed (the signal, which is fine, and something else).

Comment: @user171780 ... Right, but it was just a guess as internal "circuitry" is not known.

Comment: I am curious to know the frequency response of this amplifier (input/output matched for reference).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simulation (MiniCircuit modeling guess).
For "reference" ...

To be complete here is also the frequency response (not as good as minicircuits ... :-)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising. I added a new screenshot from the oscilloscope in which the two oscillatory components that you get in your simulation are visible (the high frequency and the low). I will try to implement your circuit here to experiment. The high frequency component I think is related to your L2.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a very large inductance in the bias tee (unknown value as it is not specified in the datasheet). I changed the bias tee by a discrete one made with a single inductor and a capacitor and I found that id the inductor is larger than 300 nH, this problem appears and is somehow proportional to the inductance, lower values than 300 nH make the amplifier to undershoot. With a 300 nH inductor it is the sweet spot where the pulses are amplified properly.